# Traceroute through IPSec tunnel

Tags: vpn, ipsec, site-to-site

## askk

Hi. When I do traceroute from host 192.168.11.0/24 to the server 10.0.0.0/24, which is site B. When the packets get into the public area it show `Request timed out` (as shown in this figure). I'm using IPSec protocol btw. thank you...  [image]

**NETWORK DIAGRAM.**
[image]

> KCP 1 (SITE A) Conf

```
Current configuration : 1284 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname KCP1
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2911/K9 sn FTX1524EEWL-
license boot module c2900 technology-package securityk9
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 1
 encr 3des
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
!
crypto isakmp key bjj address 209.165.100.1
!
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set TS esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
!
crypto map bjjtunnel 1 ipsec-isakmp 
 set peer 209.165.100.1
 set transform-set TS 
 match address vpn-ke-bjjpusat
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 209.165.101.1 255.255.255.248
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 crypto map bjjtunnel
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.11.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 209.165.101.2 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
ip access-list extended vpn-ke-bjjpusat
 permit ip 192.168.11.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip 192.168.11.0 0.0.0.255 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

> BJJPUSAT (SITE B) Conf

```
Current configuration : 1290 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname BJJPUSAT
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2911/K9 sn FTX1524I08N-
license boot module c2900 technology-package securityk9
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 1
 encr 3des
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
!
crypto isakmp key bjj address 209.165.101.1
!
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set TS esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
!
crypto map bjjtunnel 1 ipsec-isakmp 
 set peer 209.165.101.1
 set transform-set TS 
 match address vpn-ke-kcp1
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 209.165.100.1 255.255.255.248
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 crypto map bjjtunnel
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 209.165.100.2 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
ip access-list extended vpn-ke-kcp1
 permit ip 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.11.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.11.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: when i do traceroute from host 192.168.11.0/24 to the server 10.0.0.0/24 which is site B when the packets get into the public area it show 'request timed out' can u explained why ??

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

BJJPUSAT, the tunnel side towards the destination, doesn't send an *Time Exceeded* ICMP message when TTL runs out. It just silently drops the probe packet.

Note that the tunneled packet doesn't enter the public zone itself. It's encapsulated in an outer packet that crosses that zone. Accordingly, the tunnel only decrements the TTL by 1 and traceroute sees the tunnel as a single hop, regardless of the number of hops the outer packet takes.

Comment: i'd love to see ebook,or journal talking about this, if u dont mind maybe you can give me the reference

Comment: ICMP? Check out [RFC 792](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc792).